# Sqlalchemy: postgresql paramstyle for engine.execute()

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am connected to postgresql with sqlalchemy. When I try this code:

```
e = create_engine('')
r = e.execute("select ?", 5)
```

it gives me:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) syntax error at end of input
```

Corresponding to http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/connections.html?highlight=engine#sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection.execute there are different types of paramstyles... 
After deeper research, i found out that default paramstyle for postgresql Dialect is "pyformat".

Can somebody show me how to use this pyformat on some example?
I would just like to use placeholders or named placeholders for forming up the sql statement.

I tried:

```
e.execute("select %s, %s;", "test", "test2")
```

But this is not working either.

Thank you

edit:
of course, i am passing valid connection string to create_engine method :-)

Comment: I think it's the same, just replace `?` with `%s`. At least it should be so...

Comment: Yeah i thought so, but it is not working if you try it. And how to handle different datatypes? I was just typing universal method for invoking db procedure (pass *args as positional arguments of the db procedure) and I thought that sqlalchemy will handle datatypes automatically :/, with this paramstyle, i will have to pass formatting segment for each argument to my method

Comment: In my opinion, SQLAlchemy is not worth the fuss. Just use MySQL (**[pymysql](https://code.google.com/p/pymysql/ "PyMySQL: Pure Python MySQL Client")** works on Python 3, pure Python implementation) or, better yet, SQLite (**[sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sqlite3.html "DB-API 2.0 interface for SQLite databases")** is in Python Standard Library)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation you link to, directly links to PEP 249, which shows you the different styles.

About pyformat it says:

> 'pyformat'      Python extended format codes, e.g. '...WHERE
>   name=%(name)s'

So that's what you need to use.

By Googling on "DBAPI pyformat" the second link is the link to the [psycopg2 documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html). After mentioning that it uses pyformat there is a "See Also" linking to [a page with loads of examples](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters).

Examples of how to use it are in your original link:

```
e.execute("select %s, %s;", ("param1", "test"), ("param2", "test2"))
```

You can also use this syntax:

```
e.execute("select %(param1)s, %(param2)s;", param1="test", param2="test2"))
```

Which is nicer.

Comment: The example from the second link which actually uses the `pyformat` would be: `e.execute("""INSERT INTO some_table (an_int, a_date, another_date, a_string)
VALUES (%(int)s, %(date)s, %(date)s, %(str)s);""",
{'int': 10, 'str': "O'Reilly", 'date': datetime.date(2005, 11, 18)})`

Comment: @van: The first example is using just `%s` and a tuple, so both seems to work.

Comment: I do not have `postresql` to test the code; I merely state what the `pyformat` actually is as it is mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro:
I tried your code here: http://pastebin.com/CzRhABn4 
Unfortunatelly, It is not working...
When I try different parameters, the error is different: http://pastebin.com/85bZM8ym

Comment: @JoshuaBoshi: SQLAlchemy doesn't take tuples straight, it has to be one tuple for each parameter, as shown in the docs you yourself linked to. I updated the example. I doubt it is different for Python 3. The errors you get are the errors I would expect from your code after reading the docs you yourself linked to.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer was correct before the release of SqlAlchemy 1.4.

In case people searching how to do that now, here's the solution:

```py
session.connection().exec_driver_sql(
    "select %(param1)s, %(param2)s;", 
    {"param1": "test", "param2": "test2"}
)
```

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.exec_driver_sql